# how to get the monday of a years first week?

Tags: calculations, date, date-calculations

I would like to get the date of the monday of the first week of a year from only the year
The purpose is a week planner where I put one week on each page and as most of the years first weeks monday is in the last year, so I have to calculate that date
I already thought about some kind of `\ifdate{Monday}....` with many ifs to get a 'stupid' solution, but I would like an 'efficient' solution and somehow I just can't get into latex very well and I still don't understand what structures are used in this language and how that whole thing works as it is very abstract

Comment: Just to get it clear, you are here talking about a so-called “[ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)”, where the rule is that a week (which is Monday–Sunday) belongs to the year which has the majority of the week's days, or equivalently, the year of the week's Thursday?

Comment: Do you specifically need that Monday, or the week day of the 1st January?

Comment: thanks for asking! no, I want to get the monday of the week, even if the 01-01 is a sunday, so in that case I would like to get the 12-26 of the previous year

Comment: @marcoPolio do you know any efficient algorithm one could implement, that does that?

Comment: @Skillmon no not really, it doesn't really have to be efficient, I just would like to have a less stupid approach than my \ifdate{Monday}...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgfcalendar` has methods to calculate the weekday of a given date. The following uses it to define `\MondaysDateIs` as the date of the first weeks Monday of a year given to `\GetMondaysDate`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\newcount\FirstDayCount
\newcount\YearCount
\newcommand\GetMondaysDate[1]
  {%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-01-01}\FirstDayCount
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\FirstDayCount}\FirstDayCount
    \YearCount=#1
    \advance\YearCount-1
    \ifcase\FirstDayCount
      \def\MondaysDateIs{#1-01-01}%
    \or % 1
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-31}%
    \or % 2
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-30}%
    \or % 3
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-29}%
    \or % 4
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-28}%
    \or % 5
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-27}%
    \or % 6
      \edef\MondaysDateIs{\the\YearCount -12-26}%
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}
\GetMondaysDate{2019}
\MondaysDateIs
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: weell, that's kind of the approach that I thought of, but it looks a lot better than what I would have done! thanks a lot, that solves my problem completely :)