# How to get the dates of each Sunday in a month

Tags: date, date-calculations

Is there a way to cleanly calculate the dates of every Sunday in the current month? IE for this month (August 2021) it would return 1, 8, 15, 22, and 29?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How is your question related to TeX?

Comment: I was specifically looking for a latex solution, maybe with \datenumber or some other package

Comment: @tranfuria, Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469059/how-to-get-the-monday-of-a-years-first-week , using `pgfcalendar `.